# getopt for python syntax

Tags: python, input, getopt, args

I am really struggling to find a resource that actually explains the syntax of how to implement getopt using python. Every example I see has at least ten lines of code and none of them are explained. I am trying to use getopt very simply to allow from my command line to type **both** of the options listed below:

```
python test.py -i file.fa
```

AND

```
python test.py -inputfile = file.fa
```

I am a beginner so I am really struggling to understand what syntax is necessary and what is not....this is how far I have gotten and it does not work:

```
def main():
   try:
     opts,args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],":i"["inputfile=",])
   for opt,arg in opts:
        if opt == '-i':
            inputfile = arg
```

Comment: Have you tried the second option without the spaces surrounding the equal sign?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `":i"["inputfile=",]` should be `":i", ["inputfile="])`

Comment: You almost certainly want your long arguments to start with a _double_ hyphen:  `--inputfile`.  This prevents the ambiguity of a single hyphen with multiple arguments --- does a command like `program -xml` have one long argument, or three short ones?

Answer (score 2):

If using python 2.7 or higher, you might [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) easier to use, or [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) if less than 2.7.

Then there is [aaargh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aaargh/0.7.1). Each has a fairly extensive list of examples. You might need to actually install the last one using pip install or sudo pip install.